# Cast class to subclass

Tags: java, class, reflection, casting

For example. I have hundred or more classes *A, B, C...* that cannot be changed. And receive them from external source. Each of these classes have subclasses *{A1, A2, ... An}, {B1}, {C1, C2}* ...  wich I should create depending from its super classes. 
But most of supers have only **one** sub

I can see only two variants:

1. I create hundred factory methods (or constractor) for each class hierarchy to get subclasses.
   Something like:

   ```
   public static <Sub extends A> Sub buildSubClass(A superc) { 
       Sub subclass;
       if(isA1(superc)) {
          subclass = new A1();
          subclass.setField(superc.getField())
          // etc for each field of A class
       } else if(isA2(superc)) {
          subclass = new A2();
          subclass.setField(superc.getField())
          // ....
       } // etc.
       return subclass;
   }
   ```
2. Can I use reflection

   ```
   public static <S, T> T castObject(S source, Class<T> targetClass) {
       T newInstance = targetClass.newInstance();
            for (Field field : source.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
                for (Field fieldTarget : targetClass.getDeclaredFields()) {
                    if (isFieldsEqual(field, fieldTarget)) {
                        setField(getField(field, source), 
                   fieldTarget,  newInstance);
                    }
                }
            }
            return newInstance;
     }
   ```

Have java more elegant way to cast object to subclass object? Ideal way for me it just change object signature to not create new instances of A subclass but change it so that java consider it as instance of subclass object(with new fields). 
Something like:

```
A superc = new A(); 
A1 sub = (A1) superc;
```

I now it will not work, but I want something in this manner;

Comment: This isn't clear.  What are `isA1`, `isA2`, etc.?  What are you actually trying to do here?  (i.e. why do you need to dynamically create instances of these hundreds of sub-classes in a generic way?)

Comment: some abstract boolean function that determine which subclass object should be created. It doesn't matter in this context actually.

Comment: Way may be not generic. I just search way to avoid many many set(get()) statements

Comment: I would build a code generator from a list of classes named in a flat-file. Ugly, yes, but if this is a one-time piece of work, the easiest appraoch ... and build your factory class using a code generator

Answer (score 1):

To cast a variable to a subclass the variable must have been instantiated as that subclass (or a subclass of that subclass).

```
ClassA a = new SubA();
SubA sub = (SubA) a;
```

or

```
ClassA a = new SubSubA();
SubA sub = (SubA) a;
```

where

```
ClassA {...}
SubA extends ClassA{...}
SubSubA extends SubA{...}
```

To check if the object you're working with can be cast to a given class:

```
if (a instanceof SubA) {
    //safe cast
    SubA sub = (SubA) a;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for answer. I not create them myself; question updated.